# powershell with VHDL questasim 2020.4 won't accept full path to arguments file under powershell

Tags: vhdl

Anybody know what's causing this problem?  I'm trying to provided the full path to vcom.exe from powershell and vcom is removing the forward slashes:

```
PS> C:\questasim64_2020.4\win64\vcom.exe -2002 -f "C:/proj1/rtl/files.f"

QuestaSim-64 vcom 2020.4 Compiler 2020.10 Oct 13 2020
Start time: 08:46:02 on Jan 10,2022
vcom.exe -2002 -f "C:/proj1/rtl/files.f
** Error: (vcom-7) Failed to open design unit file "C:proj1rtlfiles.f" in read mode.
No such file or directory. (errno = ENOENT)
End time: 08:46:02 on Jan 10,2022, Elapsed time: 0:00:00
Errors: 1, Warnings: 0
```

cmd.exe has the same problem:

```
PS C:\proj1> cmd

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1202]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\proj1> C:\questasim64_2020.4\win64\vcom.exe -2002 -l simout.vhdl.log -f C:/proj1/rtl/files.f
QuestaSim-64 vcom 2020.4 Compiler 2020.10 Oct 13 2020
Start time: 08:46:02 on Jan 10,2022
vcom.exe -2002 -f "C:/proj1/rtl/files.f
** Error: (vcom-7) Failed to open design unit file "C:proj1rtlfiles.f" in read mode.
No such file or directory. (errno = ENOENT)
End time: 08:46:02 on Jan 10,2022, Elapsed time: 0:00:00
Errors: 1, Warnings: 0
```

I don't remember this ever being a problem before with mentor graphics...  seems like kind of a bad bug?

I tried it again using WSL-2 and Ubuntu under Windows 10:

```
PS> gci C:\Users\wpmoore\Desktop\collins\sandbox\sandbox.vsc.tbwork\out.sim\simout.work.vhd.f
-a----         1/11/2022  12:28 PM            163 simout.work.vhd.f

PS>  bash

$ uname -a
Linux PV3013 5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Fri Apr 2 22:23:49 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$  /mnt/c/questasim64_2020.4/win64/vcom.exe -2002 -l simout.vhdl.log -f " C:/Users/wpmoore/Desktop/collins/sandbox/sandbox.vsc.tbwork/out.sim/simout.work.vhd.f"
** Error: (vcom-7) Failed to open -f file " C:/Users/wpmoore/Desktop/collins/sandbox/sandbox.vsc.tbwork/out.sim/simout.work.vhd.f" in read mode.
Invalid argument. (errno = EINVAL)
QuestaSim-64 vcom 2020.4 Compiler 2020.10 Oct 13 2020
vcom -2002 -l simout.vhdl.log -f  C:/Users/wpmoore/Desktop/collins/sandbox/sandbox.vsc.tbwork/out.sim/simout.work.vhd.f
End time: 12:30:28 on Jan 11,2022, Elapsed time: 0:00:00
Errors: 1, Warnings: 0


$  /mnt/c/questasim64_2020.4/win64/vcom.exe -2002 -l simout.vhdl.log -f "C:\\Users\\wpmoore\\Desktop\\collins\\sandbox\\sandbox.vsc.tbwork\\out.sim\\simout.work.vhd.f"
QuestaSim-64 vcom 2020.4 Compiler 2020.10 Oct 13 2020
Start time: 12:32:18 on Jan 11,2022
vcom -2002 -l simout.vhdl.log -f C:\Users\wpmoore\Desktop\collins\sandbox\sandbox.vsc.tbwork\out.sim\simout.work.vhd.f
** Error: (vcom-7) Failed to open design unit file "C:UserswpmooreDesktopcollinssandboxsandbox.vsc.tbworktb_pack2.vhd" in read mode.
No such file or directory. (errno = ENOENT)
End time: 12:32:19 on Jan 11,2022, Elapsed time: 0:00:01
Errors: 1, Warnings: 0
```

Comment: have you tried using \ which is the usual windows path separator?

Comment: ahh... let me try it again...

Comment: PS C:\Users\wpmoore\Desktop\collins\sandbox\sandbox.vsc3> vcom -2002 -l simout.vhdl.log -f  C:\Users\wpmoore\Desktop\collins\sandbox\sandbox.vsc3\test0.sim\simout.synplify.vhd.f
QuestaSim-64 vcom 2020.4 Compiler 2020.10 Oct 13 2020
Start time: 10:59:28 on Jan 10,2022
vcom -2002 -l simout.vhdl.log -f C:\Users\wpmoore\Desktop\collins\sandbox\sandbox.vsc3\test0.sim\simout.synplify.vhd.f
** Error: (vcom-7) Failed to open design unit file "C:UserswpmooreDesktopcollinslibs_fpga_vendorlibs_synplifysynattr.vhd" in read mode.
No such file or directory

Comment: doesn't work either

Comment: Your attempt in the preceding comment appears to have issue with the contents of the command file simout.synplify.vhd.f, a path to synattr.vhd as opposed to the original problem - not reaching the command file.

Comment: I don't think so... however, it does the same thing by removing slashes from absolute paths in the argument files...

Comment: Have you considered using MSYS2?   It is a Linux shell that runs on top of windows.

Comment: Check out the updated question... I tried it with WSL2 on windows 10.... strangely... it doens't remove forward slashed like powershell.exe and cmd.exe but it still can't find the file... backslash still has a problem under WSL2...

Comment: Maybe questasim is secretly compiled using MSYS instead of visual studio?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use only "Forward slashes" when specifying the path to "-f" file, and also, for the files listed inside of the "-f" file.  Then it works with both powershell.exe and cmd.exe.

Example:

```
-f C:/mypath/dir1/dir2/file.f

# content of file.f:
C:/mypath/dir1/dir2/code.vhd
C:/mypath/dir1/dir2/code.v
```

The older Windows Backslashes in the path doesn't work for vsim for latest questasim... (which in my opinion is a serious bug for software claiming to work under windows)

Comment: Don't confuse windows and Linux. Wsl is Linux. Windows uses backslash. Linux (and the rest) forward slash. In your examples you're mixing them. That wouldn't work

Comment: That's because the questasim that I installed is supposely a windows 10 application.